# Does antialiasing hardware in a CPU invalidate entries conservatively?

Tags: caching, architecture, hardware, antialiasing

I'm reading through **Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach, Sixth Edition**, and there is a brief section that describes hardware antialiasing in a CPU cache:

> Hardware solutions to the synonym problem, called *antialiasing*, guarantee
>   every cache block a unique physical address. For example, the AMD Opteron uses
>   a 64 KiB instruction cache with a 4 KiB page and two-way set associativity; hence,
>   the hardware must handle aliases involved with the three virtual address bits in
>   the set index. It avoids aliases by simply checking all eight possible locations
>   on a miss—two blocks in each of four sets—to be sure that none matches the physical address of the data being fetched. If one is found, it is invalidated, so when
>   the new data are loaded into the cache their physical address is guaranteed to be
>   unique.

I understand the problem that this is supposed to solve; two different virtual addresses may refer to the same physical address, so in a virtual cache there can be a situation where more than one copy of the data at the physical address exists in the cache. Updating one of these cache entries does not update the other, which must be dealt with somehow.

I'm unclear on this part though: In the Opteron example above, the cache uses 3 bits from the virtual address to determine which of the 8 ways could contain the address. When the antialiasing hardware is checking the 8 locations to match against the physical address, is it using only the page offset bits to compare to the tags in the cache? Wouldn't this mean that it's possible to invalidate entries in the cache that have a different physical address, but just happen to share the same page offset?